# Scala Generic Array and Ordered?

Tags: arrays, scala, class, generics

So, I understand how to make generic arrays with ClassManifest and I also know how to create a class where the type is ordered. How do I combine the two?

```
class Ordered[A <% Ordered] 

class GenericArrays[A : ClassManifest] 
     val genericArray = new Array[A](10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer if anyone is interested!

```
class OrderedAndGeneric[A <% Ordered: ClassManifest]
```